# Extracting contours from high temperature image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to extract the outline of an object within a furnace, here is the image:

[image: Original]

I have tried various techniques to process the image but I have failed, the technique that gives the best image of the object is **CLAHE** as seen here:

[image: CLAHE]

Simple normalization:

[image]

I have tried Canny, Sobel, dilating, eroding and morphing but I cannot seem to get them to work harmoniously to allow me to extract the contour I want ( the contour surrounding the object in the furnace).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: there simply isn't much usable signal there. it's noisy, it's low-contrast, there appear to be *waves* across the whole image (look closely at the left edge that is all-background) and the image doesn't come with a temperature scale either. what can you improve about image acquisition?

Comment: The temperature is at around 1200degC, the only thing I can think of is to use a blue filter on the camera but because of the high temperature the emissivity of everything in the furnace will become the same so contrasting will be difficult regardless.

Comment: are you hoping to see anything in a thermal/IR image when everything's expected to be roughly the same temperature anyway? I'd recommend adding an IR filter instead, so you only get visible light, and not the overwhelming intensity of thermal infrared. if your human eyes can see the object, limit the spectrum to visible light.

Comment: IR filter is a great idea, I have also come up with putting a steel plate in the background to give contrasting emissivity. Do you think it is impossible to extract with the given set up?

Comment: Definitely modify your background, if you can put some cooler object there. If you can get better contrast, then that should help. Alternately, possibly take multiple exposures and combine them to help reduce the noise.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/is-it-possible-to-collect-contours-from-this-image/8503

Answer (score 0):

Histogram equalization followed by strong Gaussian filtering in the horizontal or vertical directions will enhance the near-horizontal and near-vertical edges (separately). That's about the best you can do. (Maybe try Hough on these.)

[image]

[image]

Also notice that the specialized edge fitters as found in typical gauging libraries can help you if the geometry is roughly known.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm fairly new to this how do you access these specialized edge fitters?

Comment: or more specifically, what are such libraries and... do these white dots represent *handles* of a draggable rectangle in a rapid prototyping GUI one could use?

Comment: @Curb: these are available in commercial products, in the field of machine vision software.

Comment: I would need to move onto more complex shapes in the future, would any of this software be able to identify such objects?

Comment: If you know the shape in advance and can model it, that can be possible. Otherwise, the image is too bad.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I will know the shape in advance, could you point me in the right direction for a machine vision software that could help me with this please?

Comment: @Curb: you can visit the website in my profile.